# How to query highest value from table column in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

For example, I have table with a column `ID` as seen below:

```
  ID  
------
  1 
  2
  3 
  4
```

How can I query so I can get 4?

I'm using SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select max(ID) from [Table]
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4cbf2/1)

Answer (score 2):

You should use `SELECT max(Id) FROM mytable`

And you should be able to accomplish that using code like this:

```
    int maxId = -1;
    string connectionString = "yourConnectionString";
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT max(Id) FROM mytable", con))
            {
                maxId = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID
FROM mytable
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

to forego calculation and utilize a sort feature to find the highest value in whatever column you're checking.

Thanks,

C§